# Background image not appearing in mobile device

Tags: html, css

I am encountering an issue where a background image is displayed on my website on the laptop (chrome and safari) but when I use the same browsers on mobile, the background image does not appear and I am not sure why?

Below is my css:

```
#callToAction
{
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url(../img/17545.jpg);
    background:url(../img/17545.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

The actual image size is 1280x475

If you want to see it for yourself, go onto our website https://www.metis-online.com and it's the call to action background image where it states 'Get Certified Today'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working for me, I think since your `background-size` is `cover` that the left and right just are out of the viewport and it's just white *(if that's what you mean with 'not appearing')*..

Try this:

```css
#callToAction
{
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: This has worked, thank you. Will mark answer when it lets me in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Image didn't appearing because cover displayed white area of Image

Use follwing code in media query

`background-size: 100% 100%;`

OR this one

`background-size: 150vw 100vh`

```
#callToAction {
        padding-top: 80px;
        padding-bottom: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        background-image: url(../img/17545.jpg);
        background: url(../img/17545.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%; /* <-- Replace Cover with 100% */
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the CONTAIN command in css resizes your image according to your box size you have defined or to your screen ratio and COVER command uses the full space you i've defined weather the image fits or not in screen so CONTAIN command will work properly